# send information from react form to my email

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have this form and I need that when someone fills it out and clicks on the button to send an email to my address filled in by emailjs but when I try to send me a test email it gives me an error Cannot read property 'send' of undefined. I've already looked in the documentation but there is nothing that can help me. Someone know how to fix this?

```
      this.state = {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            feedback: "",
          };
        }
      handleInputChange(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          const target = event.target;
          const name = target.name;
          const value = target.value;
          
      this.setState({ [name]: value });
        }
        sendMessage(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
    const templateParams = {
          from_name: this.state.name + " (" + this.state.email + ")",
          to_name:'my email',
          feedback: this.state.feedback
        };
    
    emailjs.send("gmail", "my template id", templateParams)
          .then(
            function(response) {
              toast.success("Your message has successfully sent!", {
                position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER
              });
              console.log("SUCCESS!", response.status, response.text);
            },
            function(err) {
              console.log("Your message was not able to be sent");
            }
          );
    this.setState({
          name: "",
          email: "",
          feedback: ""
        });
      }
        render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <form
                  className="ui form"
                  id={this.props.id}
                  name={this.props.name}
                  method={this.props.method}
                  action={this.props.action}
                >
                  <textarea
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}
                    placeholder="your name"
                    required
                    value={this.state.name}
                    style={{ width: "100%" }}
                    rows={1}
                  />
                  <br />
                  <textarea
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}
                    placeholder="your email address"
                    required
                    value={this.state.email}
                    style={{ width: "100%" }}
                    rows={1}
                  />
                  <br />
                  <textarea
                    id="feedback"
                    name="feedback"
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}
                    placeholder="what would you like to chat about?"
                    required
                    value={this.state.feedback}
                    style={{ width: "100%", height: "250px" }}
                  />
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="button"
                    value="Send"
                    className="ui button"
                    style={{
                      
                      fontSize: "20px",
                      color: "blue"
                    }}
                    onClick={this.sendMessage.bind(this)}
                  />
```

Comment: Have you imported `emailjs`? Or have you defined it? You need to import and create a client as mentioned in docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs

Comment: I've imported emailjs with import {emailjs, init}

Comment: But the error is "send of undefined", can you try printing it's value using console log? What does it print?